# How to fix Roblox "Error Code 275"?

Tags: roblox

I updated my game and now "Roblox has shut down this server for maintenance, error code 275" has appeared. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In Roblox, if an error has occurred in the game, a dialog box will show up with a  "Roblox has shut down this game server for maintenance (Error Code: 275)". You just have to reload the page again, or wait until the error is resolved. I think that the upgrading of your game doesn't matter. It's probably a coincidence.